# htaccess file - root and website folder htaccess file both have different code. URL does not work without the www

Tags: .htaccess, no-www

I have the following domain that does not work without the www.

[www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com) works
mydomain.com = does not work

The root htaccess file (primary domain is something else) automatically seemed to have this code in it.

```
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.mydomain\.io\/mydomain" [R=301,L]
```

I added this code in the website's own htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Currently mydomain.com goes to something quite strange (it duplicates the domain name): and has an error

```
https://www.example.com/example.com/
```

Error on page

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Can I delete the code which says "do not edit". Which one is working and why/how?

Comment: Please include your complete `.htaccess` file. Nothing in what you've posted (taken out of context) explains the behaviour you are seeing.

Comment: "The root htaccess file (primary domain is something else)" - What do you mean by "primary domain is something else"? Do you have multiple domains? Multiple (nested) `.htaccess` files?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was basically resolved by:

1. Adding the rewrite engine rules:

   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
2. Deleting the forwarding in the DNS management console and ONLY leaving in the forwarding in the addondomains section. So, in the cpanel - addon domains, create forwarding and delete the forwarding in the DNS section. This was the key part.
3. There was an additional folder outside of the public_html for this domain and that was deleted as well.

Finally, adding these rules to force https was useful:

https://www.hostinger.co.uk/tutorials/ssl/forcing-https

Also noting the helpful comment: "Which web server are you using? Look through your web server configuration files. Your problem is that you have a redirect from HTTP to HTTPS and the path URL is configured wrong."